# Multi language support while migrating from db2 to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, db2, database-migration, multilingual

I have a database in db2 that needs to be migrated to mysql. I am exporting data from db2 to csv and then csv to mysql. The data is in multiple languages like Chinese, French, Latin, Hebrew, etc. Due to character set issues, the data is converted into symbols. How shall I ensure that the import is done correctly without any changes in the data ?

Comment: Check which collation is set in db2 and use that in MySQL too - ensure that both the connection and the destination rows know about that collation

Comment: The collation for db2 and mysql is set to UTF8.. I think UTF-8 does not support french. Is it true?

Comment: The collation does not care about the *language* of your input, but about the specific characters. Can you add the input manually to your database, eg. through phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or using MySQL on a shell?

Comment: How exactly do you export your data? Please post the exact command you're running.

Answer (score 0):

If the Db2 data is encoded in UTF-8, and your target is UTF-8  *and especially if your LOCALE is correctly set on the export from Db2* then you won't lose any data.

If your LOCALE is incorrect or if you use the wrong export options from Db2 then there is a risk of data conversion issues. The way to set the locale depends on the operating-system where you run the EXPORT command from Db2 and the command-line options you give the Db2 EXPORt command.